# Map reference confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I encountered with some weird problem. I have class which store its values inside map. But in one case I need to expose map to do some external calculation and possible adding of data inside that map.

And I have next problem. I have shared_ptr of that class and expose map through reference, but during processing map wont accept new data.

I wrote some dummy example of that just to be clear. What is happening here? And why?

Why changes made to map won't hold up after function end?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MapWrap {
public:
  MapWrap() {}
  ~MapWrap(){}

  std::map<int, int>& getMap() { return map; }
private:
  std::map<int, int> map;
};

void goGo(std::shared_ptr<MapWrap> m){
  auto map = m->getMap();
  std::cout << "Func: before: map size: " << map.size() << std::endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    // This should and will add new value to map.
    if(map[i] == 3){
      std::cout << "blah" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Func: after: map size: " << map.size() << std::endl;
}

int main(){

  auto mapWrap = std::make_shared<MapWrap>();

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
     goGo(mapWrap);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Removed const from getMap() method.

Comment: Don't use shared_ptr as parameter if you do not want to share ownership. Use a raw pointer or better a reference if the parameter is not intended to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
auto map = m->getMap();
```

type of map is `std::map<int, int>` so you make a copy and you modify this copy. Change it to :

```
auto& map = m->getMap();
```

and you will modify the passed map instead of copy.

btw. if you dont know what type your auto variable have, you can always use compiler errors to check this:

```
template<typename T> struct TD;

auto map = m->getMap();
TD<decltype(map)> dd;
```

will result in:

```
main.cpp:19:21: error: aggregate 'TD<std::map<int, int> > dd' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   TD<decltype(map)> dd;
```

here you can read `map` type is `std::map<int, int>`